# How to create a payment method for testing in Laravel Cashier with phpunit and stripe

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, stripe-payments

I have one issue and I hope you can help me, in the browser, my app works fine, but if I try to test it in phpunit, it is not passing the test.

I am hitting the real stripe api as the laravel docs says:
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/billing#testing

But I am using it on testing mode, in the browser I just use a testing credit card number: 4242424242424242 , as is mentioned here: https://stripe.com/docs/testing

In my controller I have this:

```
....
DB::beginTransaction();            
           
$user = User::firstOrCreate([                    
        'email' => $request->user_email
 ],
 [                                     
 'name' => $request->user_name,   
 'password' => Hash::make($request->user_password)
]        
 );            

$user->createOrGetStripeCustomer();
....
....
$user->charge($amount, $request->payment_method_id);

Mail::send(new ProjectCreated($project));
....
....
```

ProjectTest.php

```
...
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use App\Mail\ProjectCreated;

class ProjectTest extends TestCase
{
    use RefreshDatabase;

    public function test_an_email_is_sent_when_a_project_is_submitted()
    {                
        //given        
        Mail::fake();        

        // when
        $project = Project::factory()->make();          

        $response = $this->post(route('projects.store'), $project->toArray()+['payment_method_id' => 'test']);            

        //then
        $response->assertOk();
    }
}
```

phpunit.xml

```
<server name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
<server name="BCRYPT_ROUNDS" value="4"/>
<server name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
<server name="DB_CONNECTION" value="sqlite"/>
<server name="DB_DATABASE" value=":memory:"/>
<server name="MAIL_MAILER" value="log"/>
<server name="STRIPE_SECRET" value="sk_test_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"/>                
<server name="QUEUE_CONNECTION" value="sync"/>
<server name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
<server name="TELESCOPE_ENABLED" value="false"/>
```

Phpunit message:

> No such PaymentMethod: 'test'

How could I create a payment method for testing? or should it be better not to hit the stripe api? how do you do it in your projects? thanks.

Comment: Don't have any experience with Laravel Cashier or phpunit, but if you just need to create a test payment method then that is pretty easy to do via the [Stripe API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/create) or [dashboard](https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/dashboard).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to do add any of these payment methods: **pm_card_visa**, **pm_card_visa_debit**, etc, here are the complete list: https://stripe.com/docs/testing?testing-method=payment-methods

```
public function test_an_email_is_sent_when_a_project_is_submitted()
    {                
        //given        
        Mail::fake();        

        // when
        $project = Project::factory()->make();          

        $response = $this->post(route('projects.store'), 
        $project->toArray()+['payment_method_id' => 'pm_card_visa']);            

        //then
        $response->assertOk();
    }
```

Thank you.